# calling wordpress custom page elements

Tags: wordpress

i really hope for a help here

i'm making custom page plugin using wordpress , i want to call the elements but no matter what i use , i still cant call the page elements out , i need someone to help me know how i can call the title , content , and featured image out in the front end

the custom page plugin code

```
<?php add_action('init', 'create_services');
function create_services() {
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); 
    /*set_post_thumbnail_size(1680, 800);*/
}   
register_taxonomy(
    'service_categories',
    'services',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'Service Categories',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'service_categories',
            'with_front' => false
        )
    ));

register_post_type('services', 
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Services',
            'singular_name' => 'Service',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Services',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Service',
            'new_item' => 'New Service',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Service',
            'search_items' => 'Search Service',
            'not_found' => 'No Services found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Services found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Service'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'service_categories' ),
        'has_archive' => true
    )
);
add_image_size('service-image', 650, 430);?>
```

i active the plugin and it shows service plugin , 
i make a post and put the content like this
[image: pic1]
and in services categories page
[image: pic2]

in front end (index.php) , i tried calling the title , content and featured picture like this

```
                <?php 
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 'services=contract' ); 
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                $the_query->the_post();
                the_title();
                the_content();
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

but it didnt show me the posts i put in the custom page , can someone help me with this , thanks! , sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your taxonomy needs to be addressed in your parenthesis after the WP query

Here is a sample from wordpress codex

```
// The Query
 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'service_categories' => 'contract'
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );


// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I would start with this and then add or manipulate this code until you get the results you are looking for. Like adding the images and all.

Here is the link to this [article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: ok , so after i use the code , how can i call the posts , or title , or featured images?